# Left join not producing expected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I did a little research before pestering anyone with my question and I can't seem to find a relevant solution.

I'm working with two tables in a database, one called `jobs` and the other called `jobsClosed`. Jobs that are in the `jobs` table that are not in `jobsClosed` (`JobID` and `SubJobId` must both be considered) are open jobs and closed otherwise. Below are examples of the two tables. Now, in these examples, I'm including only the fields with data I'm concerned with. The actual tables I'm working with have many many more fields (which I suspect is why I'm not getting the results I expect).

`jobs`

```
Company     JobID       SubJobID        NoOfSubJobs
Company1     A                              1
Company1     A              1               0
```

`jobsClosed`

```
Company     JobID       SubJobID        
Company1     A              1
```

Some jobs have a blank entry under `SubJobID`.

All I need is jobs that are still open. So, using this query:

```
select *
from jobs as j
left join jobsClosed as c 
      on j.Company  = c.Company 
     and j.JobID    = c.JobID 
     and c.SubJobID = j.SubJobID
where c.Company = 'Company1' --the database has multiple companies and I'm only concerned with this one
  and c.JobID is null
```

I expected to get in the actual tables I'm using:

```
Company     JobID   SubJobID    NoOfSubJobs     Company     JobID   SubJobID
Company1      A                     1            NULL        NULL     NULL
```

But I instead got:

```
Company     JobID   SubJobID    NoOfSubJobs     Company     JobID   SubJobID
Company1      A         1           0           Company1      A         1
```

After spending some time trying to figure out why, I'm still not exactly sure. Like I mentioned before, the tables I'm basing my examples off of contain more fields, but I'm still joining them in the same manner detailed above. Could it be that other fields are somehow distorting the results?

UPDATE: So I tried using both Gordon Linoff and Jarlh's suggestions, but it appears that the resulting queries are picking up jobs that do not belong to `Company1`.

Comment: You have a condition c.Company = 'Company1' and you expect c.Company = null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `c.Company = 'Company1'` condition from `WHERE` to `ON` to get true `LEFT JOIN` result:

```
select *
from jobs as j
left join jobsClosed as c on j.Company = c.Company and j.JobID = c.JobID and 
c.SubJobID = j.SubJobID
AND c.Company = 'Company1' --the database has multiple companies and I'm only concerned with this one
WHERE c.JobID is null
```

If you have right side table conditions in the WHERE clause like that, your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: I gave this a shot and the result is giving me jobs that do not pertain to `Company1` despite me including it as you demonstrated.

Comment: Filter on `j.Company`, not the inner side of the join.

Comment: That did it! Thanks shawnt00

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `not exists`, because that seems to be what you really want:

```
select j.*
from jobs j
where not exists (select 1
                  from jobsClosed c 
                  where j.Company = c.Company and j.JobID = c.JobID and 
                        c.SubJobID = j.SubJobID and c.Company = 'Company1'
                 );
```

Comment: I apologize. I initially thought this worked, but upon review I noticed that I was getting jobs for companies not pertaining to `Company1` in the results. Any suggestions?

Comment: Filter on `j.Company` in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

> according to your exemple, the request doesn't return any think;
>   causes of your join clause criteria! and how you got NULL values from
>   JobsClosed with **Left** join????

---

```
-- if opened jobs are identified by null values on Jobs.SubJobID:
    SELECT j.* FROM
    Jobs AS j
    LEFT JOIN JobsClosed AS c
    ON  j.company = c.company and
        j.JobID = c.JobID

    WHERE (j.Company = 'Company1') AND
          -- if opened jobs are identified by null values on Jobs.SubJobID:
          (j.SubJobID is NULL)
          -- if opened jobs are identified by Jobs.NoOfSubJobs > 0:
          -- (j.NoOfSubJobs > 0)
```

---

> Jobs that are in the jobs table that are not in jobsClosed (JobID and SubJobId must both be considered) are open jobs and closed otherwise.
>   **@Gordon Linoff** already answered your question.